# Why am I getting SuperNotCalledException when retrieving object by _id from Sqlite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve one row of data by it's **_id** and make an instance of **Inoculation** with the data I get back.

```
public Inoculation retrieveInoculationById(int id) {
  Inoculation inoculation = new Inoculation();
  Cursor cursor = getDataById(InoculationsDao.TABLE_NAME, InoculationsDao.ID, id);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
      inoculation.setBatchNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(InoculationsDao.BATCH_NUMBER)));
      inoculation.setAdministrationSite(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(InoculationsDao.ADMINISTRATION_SITE)));
      inoculation.setAdministrationDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(InoculationsDao.DATE)));
    }
  }
  cursor.close();
  return inoculation;

}
```

The `getDataById` method is simply:

```
public Cursor getDataById(String TABLE_NAME, String ID, int id) {
    Cursor cursor = databaseConnection.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + ID + " = " + id , null);
    return cursor;
}
```

It seems to fail in the `rawQuery` string.

Comment: There are at least two problems with the code you posted - SQL syntax error, lack of `cursor.moveToNext()`. Neither of those produces `SuperNotCalledException`. Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. The issue has now been fixed. It was the pesky missing space in the SQL query that ישו אוהב אותך has already pointed out. It was this SQL error that was causing the `SuperNotCalledException`. Bizarre, I know.
There is no `cursor.moveToNext()` because I am only interested in the one row since I'm retrieving one object by it's `_id`.

Comment: The `while` loop never terminates without a `cursor.moveToNext()`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `rawQuery` string is wrong because you're missing a space.

Where:

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnection.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + ID + " = " + id , null);
```

Will produce a query:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAMEWHERE ID  = id"
```

Should be:

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnection.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ID + " = " + id , null);
```

---

Instead using rawQuery, you can use [query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Something like this:

```
// Your table columns:
private String[] allColumns = { ID, YOUR_OTHER_COLUMN };

Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, allColumns, ID + " = " + id, null,
                                null, null, null);
```